# Android - set action bar height as a fraction of total height

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, height, android-layout-weight

I am developing an Android application that has an action bar. I know how to set height of action bar in pixels, but I would like to set action bar's height to be 15% of screen's height. Is that possible? Here is what I have so far in my resources file:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:height">90dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You can't do that with XML alone. You may be able to do it by writing a custom view.

Comment: Use toolbar instead,,,,,

Comment: @Ishrat - I believe toolbars would only work with the latest Android API, and I don't want to limit my app like that, though it could be a good solution.

Comment: @user3623874 :  No Toolbar is available for all previous version also, Please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code, to set custom height of ActionBar,

Compatible toolbar for previous versions of Android,Custom height is set in my case i set 100dp instead of 48dp default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<-- Your other component or xml code goes here...!-->

</LinearLayout >
```